# SimpleCov reports not generating in Rails 3 app after running RSpec tests with Spork

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, code-coverage, ruby-on-rails-3.2, spork

I just installed the [SimpleCov](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov) gem to generate code coverage reports on my Rails 3.2.6 app, and it works great with RSpec, just not with Spork.  I am able to get the desired correct report by running `rspec --no-drb spec/`, but I'd like to also get them with Spork running using just `rspec spec/`.

Given that there have been people who have had success with this, it seems likely I have errors in my setup.  I have [read through the setup instructions](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/blob/master/README.md) as well as the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/42) that purports to have a fix for Spork users, but still no luck.  I'm wondering if there is anyone who can provide a full example of their working **spec/spec_helper.rb** file that I could use for reference, as extensive Googling has only turned up snippets.  On the advice of other sites, I've tried changing the `config.cache_classes` in **config/environments/test.rb** from the default of `true` to `false` to `!(ENV['DRB'] == 'true')`, with no luck.

For reference, this is how I'm setup:

**Gemfile**

```
group :development, :test do
  # ...
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.10.1'
end

group :test do
  # ...
  gem 'spork', '0.9.0'
  gem 'simplecov', '0.6.4', require: false
end
```

**.spec**

```
--colour
--drb
```

**spec/spec_helper.rb** (changed as per the [GitHub issue](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/42))

```
require 'simplecov'
SimpleCov.start 'rails'

require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  unless ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  if ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end
end
```

I've tried commenting out/changing the top two `SimpleCov` statements of this file and the Simplecov statements inside the `Spork` blocks, but can't seem to find a combination that works.

What am I missing?  Are there any other files I need to change?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I managed to get a working **spec/spec_helper.rb** configuration that executes SimpleCov correctly simply using the `$ rspec spec/` command thanks to [a comment on the Github issue](https://github.com/colszowka/simplecov/issues/42#issuecomment-7148628) that sent me to [this blog entry](http://rickyrobinson.id.au/2012/07/20/when-spork-puts-a-fork-in-your-cucumber-and-a-spanner-in-your-specs), and [its example **spec/spec_helper.rb**](http://rickyrobinson.id.au/2012/07/20/when-spork-puts-a-fork-in-your-cucumber-and-a-spanner-in-your-specs#spec_helper.rb).  All reasons *why* this works are contained in the (very detailed!) blog entry.  Replace `SampleApp` with the name of your application.

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  unless ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end

  require 'rails/application'
  require Rails.root.join("config/application")

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec
    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    config.before :each do
      if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      else
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end

Spork.each_run do
  if ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
    SampleApp::Application.initialize!
    class SampleApp::Application
      def initialize!; end
    end
  end

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
end
```

#### Edit

If you use [Travis-CI](http://travis-ci.org/), don't use this code as-is because you'll likely get a `undefined method 'root' for Rails:Module (NoMethodError)` error.  If you know how to fix this, please share.

#### Edit 2

I got Travis CI to work by essentially putting everything in the `Spork.each_run` block, which seems to have slowed down the tests significantly.  There must be a better way to do this, or it just doesn't seem worth it for the sake of not having to run `$ rspec --no-drb spec/` once to get the SimpleCov report...

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'

Spork.prefork do
  unless ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
  end

  require 'rails/application'
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
end

Spork.each_run do
  if ENV['DRB']
    require 'simplecov'
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
    require Rails.root.join("config/application")
    SampleApp::Application.initialize!
    class SampleApp::Application
      def initialize!; end
    end
  end

  unless ENV['DRB']
    require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  end

  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec

    config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false
    config.before :each do
      if Capybara.current_driver == :rack_test
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      else
        DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
      end
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  end
end
```

#### Edit 3

After using this config for a few days, it doesn't seem to have slowed down things as much as I previously thought, so I'll consider this the accepted answer unless a more elegant one  is posted.

#### Edit 4

After using this config for a few months, I've come to realize that it *is* slower than I thought.  Part of that is the realisation that it seems that Spork can slow down test suites, and is best for fast iterative focused testing vs always running entire test suites with it.  The following SO questions and blog posts got me to the **spec_helper.rb** file below, which can run SimpleCov with or without Spork, runs faster than before, and works with Capybara 2.0.

- [Rails project using spork - always have to use spork?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8192636/567863)
- [How to profile RSpec with perftools and bundler?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9680481/567863)
- [Spork.trap_method Jujitsu](https://github.com/sporkrb/spork/wiki/Spork.trap_method-Jujitsu)
- [When Spork puts a fork in your Cucumber and a spanner in yor specs](http://rickyrobinson.id.au/2012/07/20/when-spork-puts-a-fork-in-your-cucumber-and-a-spanner-in-your-specs)
- [Crank your specs](http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/02/02/crank-your-specs/)
- [Profiling Spork for faster start-up time](http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/profiling-spork-for-faster-start-up-time/)
- [Sane RSpec config for clean, and slightly faster, specs](http://highgroove.com/articles/2012/04/06/sane-rspec-config-for-clean,-and-slightly-faster,-specs.html)

**spec/spec_helper.rb**

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'spork'
require 'simplecov'
#uncomment the following line to use spork with the debugger
#require 'spork/ext/ruby-debug'

Spork.prefork do
  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
  unless ENV['DRB']
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
    require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  end

  require 'rspec/rails'
  require 'rspec/autorun'
  require 'capybara/rails'
  require 'capybara/rspec'

  # files to preload based on results of Kernel override code below
  # ie they took more than 100 ms to load
  require "sprockets"
  require "sprockets/eco_template"
  require "sprockets/base"
  require "active_record/connection_adapters/postgresql_adapter"
  require "tzinfo"
  require "tilt"
  require "journey"
  require "journey/router"
  require "haml/template"

  RSpec.configure do |config|
    config.mock_with :rspec

    # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
    # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
    # instead of true.
    config.use_transactional_fixtures = false

    # If true, the base class of anonymous controllers will be inferred
    # automatically. This will be the default behavior in future versions of
    # rspec-rails.
    config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false

    config.include FactoryGirl::Syntax::Methods

    config.before :suite do
      # PerfTools::CpuProfiler.start("/tmp/rspec_profile")
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
      DatabaseCleaner.clean_with(:truncation)
    end

    # Request specs cannot use a transaction because Capybara runs in a
    # separate thread with a different database connection.
    config.before type: :request do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :truncation
    end

    # Reset so other non-request specs don't have to deal with slow truncation.
    config.after type: :request  do
      DatabaseCleaner.strategy = :transaction
    end

    RESERVED_IVARS = %w(@loaded_fixtures)
    last_gc_run = Time.now

    config.before(:each) do
      GC.disable
    end

    config.before do
      DatabaseCleaner.start
    end

    config.after do
      DatabaseCleaner.clean
    end

    # Release instance variables and trigger garbage collection
    # manually every second to make tests faster
    # http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/02/02/crank-your-specs/
    config.after(:each) do
      (instance_variables - RESERVED_IVARS).each do |ivar|
        instance_variable_set(ivar, nil)
      end
      if Time.now - last_gc_run > 1.0
        GC.enable
        GC.start
        last_gc_run = Time.now
      end
    end

    config.after :suite do
      # PerfTools::CpuProfiler.stop

      # REPL to query ObjectSpace
      # http://blog.carbonfive.com/2011/02/02/crank-your-specs/
      # while true
      #   '> '.display
      #   begin
      #     puts eval($stdin.gets)
      #   rescue Exception => e
      #     puts e.message
      #   end
      # end
    end
  end

  # Find files to put into preload
  # http://www.opinionatedprogrammer.com/2011/02/profiling-spork-for-faster-start-up-time/
  # module Kernel
  #   def require_with_trace(*args)
  #     start = Time.now.to_f
  #     @indent ||= 0
  #     @indent += 2
  #     require_without_trace(*args)
  #     @indent -= 2
  #     Kernel::puts "#{' '*@indent}#{((Time.now.to_f - start)*1000).to_i} #{args[0]}"
  #   end
  #   alias_method_chain :require, :trace
  # end
end

Spork.each_run do
  # This code will be run each time you run your specs.
  if ENV['DRB']
    SimpleCov.start 'rails'
    SampleApp::Application.initialize!
    class SampleApp::Application
      def initialize!; end
    end
  end

  # Requires supporting ruby files with custom matchers and macros, etc,
  # in spec/support/ and its subdirectories.
  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each {|f| require f}
  FactoryGirl.reload
  I18n.backend.reload!
end
```

Answer (score 2):

I have this working in a Rails app with these specific versions:

- `rails` (3.2.8)
- `guard` (1.3.2)
- `guard-spork` (1.1.0)
- `spork` (0.9.2)
- `simplecov` (0.6.4)
- `rspec-rails` (2.11.0)

The `spec/spec_helper.rb` looks like this:

```
require "spork"

Spork.prefork do

end

Spork.each_run do
  require "simplecov"
  SimpleCov.start "rails"

  ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
  require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
  require "rspec/rails"
  require "capybara/rspec"

  Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }

  FactoryGirl.reload
end
```

While it is probably less-than-ideal to require everything in the `Spork.each_run` block from a performance standpoint, this correctly runs SimpleCov on every test invocation and appears to have relatively low overhead.

I hope that helps. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer.  I upgraded my ruby gems to match yours and I gave your `spec_helper.rb` a test run, but unfortunately it didn't work for me; it actually ended up making some of my tests fail.  Does my `spec_helper.rb` work in your app by any chance?

Comment: Thanks for prompting me to have a look at this again.  I managed to fix my problem using the code in my answer.  Hopefully it works for you as well, or at least provides some kind of reference.

Comment: Hi Paul, that `spec_helper.rb` was extracted from a working application, though not one that uses Travis at the moment. I'm glad you got it working though!