# Speeding up RSpec & Factory girl model tests?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rspec, factory-bot

I'm currently using FactoryGirl and Rspec to test my models, which is great but incredibly slow.  The hundreds of tests that I have for each model take about 30 seconds to run, per model.

The core issue is that when I create an object to test, I'm using the `FactoryGirl.create()` method.  That hits the DB, and is definitely slower than using `build` or `build_stubbed`.  But if I just use build, then I'll never know if I run into an error with the database right (such as trying to write a null value to a column that I've specified as non-null)?

Is there any way to get the best of both world?  Or should I test the DB integration part explicitly somewhere outside of model/unit tests?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't know if this is applicable in your case, but have you considered tweaking your **spec_helper.rb** to get your suite to run faster?

I documented the evolution of my **spec_helper.rb** file in [this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12215946/567863) (see specifically Edit 4), and the links to other SO answers and blogs listed there helped me a lot in reducing the running time of the suite.

Comment: After reading that link and a few crossposts, I came across this:  http://37signals.com/svn/posts/2742-the-road-to-faster-tests

It has helped tremendously, so thanks for indirectly getting me there.

Answer (score 1):

I tend to use FactoryGirl.build, or just `.new` to create instances in model specs, and then save them only if the test needs to check some behavior that requires a persisted instance.

This can be problematic when using associations or joins where the row ID must be present. It's something of a tradeoff--speedy tests vs. tests that are easy to write.

Answer (score 0):

you should use build most of the times, I you want to be sure that some value won't be saved as null do some spec just for that, it has no sense to always create the objects on the db

if you test that the factory creates a valid object once then you can trust the factory that it will create valid objects always.

also, always use presence validations on the fields that can't be null/nil, if your field is not nil then you can be sure the db won't have a null value